# local API of a device

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to interact with an [energy meter](https://rainforestautomation.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/EAGLE-200-Local-API-Manual-v1.0.pdf) that hosts its own local API to get data. I am far from having a lot of HTTP requests knowledge and this maybe asking a lot from Stackoverflow, but how do I interact with this device on a local area network?

The directions state the HTTP request needs to consist of the following:

`<headers>` are a variable number of HTTP headers; each header is on its own line.
The following items must be included in the headers:

o Content-type: text/xml

o Content-Length: xx where “xx” is the number of characters in the body of the POST

o Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx where the 32-character Basic Authentication credential is formed using the EAGLE Cloud ID as the username, and the EAGLE Install Code as the password.

Ultimately I am trying to do this listed below (get meter data):

To get data from the meter, you must first discover its Hardware Address. This can be done by issuing a “device_list” command to the EAGLE through the Local API, which is done by sending a POST with the following text in the body:

```
<Command>
 <Name>device_list</Name>
</Command>
```

Could anyone give me a tip on how to do this with Python requests? The code below returns a 401 as I know it doesnt incorporate the body & required header information.

```
import requests

url = "http://10.100.100.27/"


print(requests.post(url).text)
```

This is an example of what the POST request should look like from the docs.
[image]

Comment: Sending post data and headers can be seen in the examples https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/  You will also want to add `/cgi-bin/post_manager` to your url

Comment: Ok thanks. Would the body requirement be `payload = {'Command': 'wifi_status'}`?

Comment: You'd want `payload` to be an XML string, not a dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
import requests

url = "http://10.100.100.27/cgi-bin/post_manager"

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
  'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + '<your api key>',
}

command = 'device_list'
payload = '<Command><Name>{}</Name></Command>'.format(command)

print(requests.post(url, headers=headers, payload=payload).text)
```